# Publish Apps to MobileIron or AirWatch

Tags: mdm

I am working for a software company, which is currently thinking about cooperating with MobileIron or possibly AirWatch. Basically my company is building a tool that allows people to create apps and we'd like to give users a "one click publish" to MDM products like MobileIron and AirWatch. I'm wondering if there's a way to connect the two systems to make this possible. For example, is there specific data we need to send with the app file to Mobile Iron or AirWatch?

A use case would be:

1. I create my app in my creation tool.
2. When I'm done I click a "publish" button.
3. The app is automatically saved up to the MDM.
4. The MDM administrator can use the normal process for that MDM to deploy it to users.

Some words please? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do not know if MDM like MobileIron or AirWatch are doing this kind of links.

I am working on a product, [Appaloosa-Store](http://www.appaloosa-store.com), which provides a way to easily distribute your apps to your users. It is more like MAM than MDM, but we provide security features.

We provide a Jenkins pluggin and an API to automatically deploy your applications on your own private store. Moreover, we can discuss about a custom link between your service and our.

A use case would be:

1. Create the app
2. Give your store token (from Appaloosa-Store)
3. Click on publish
4. The app is automatically published on Appaloosa-Store
5. Administrator can use the normal process to deploy it to users

Do not hesitate to [create an account](http://www.appaloosa-store.com) and contact us if you need more informations.

Chris
Developer - [Appaloosa Team](http://www.appaloosa-store.com/about_us)

Answer (score 2):

MobileIron is an upload interface for the admin in forms of a wizard. Today there is unfortunately no API that can be used to place the file into the correct area.
Your idea is interesting though and I will bring it up here within MobileIron.

There are couple of question that I can think of right now that would break the model:

The apps are targeted to different uses - would the dev always know whom to target? This is where the wizard comes into play.
IF the answer is no - would it be Ok if there is a "staging" area where the app can be placed and the admin targets the users?

What benefit is there for using the API vs the existing upload wizard?

If you can clarify, it would help to add this request to a future feature list

Comment: An API to upload apps would definitely be a plus. The benefit of an API is that you're able to automate things. We're using a build server which tests and builds apps. It would be great if we could do the final step: upload to MobileIron. I wish it would work a bit like Sonatype's Nexus: uploading/downloading (maven) artifacts is possible via an api, management is just defining groups, ...

Comment: Would love to have this feature in MobileIron +1

Answer (score 0):

May or may not, depends on your application's complexity.

Actually you need some adaption code for your application to work with MobileIron or AirWatch separately. For example you need use AirWatch's SDK to get the authorization status for your application on a device to ensure Enterprise Mobility Management, it may not be appropriate to include such code in the application variant for MobileIron.

I suppose you need generate 3 application variants for public, AirWatch and MobileIron to meet the different usage, then you can

1. add the AirWatch application variant to AiwWatch management console
   to publish it,
2. wrap the MobileIron application variant on MobileIron online support
   site and publish it on the MobileIron management console.

Another thing need to take into consideration is the user role, because you wrap the MobileIron variant as a "Developer" role, but a "enterprise administrator" role is the one who publishes the application inside the enterprise.